# Extracting original objects from jList

Tags: java, jlist

I have added combined values to`jList` by the code `listModel.addElement(Integer + "-" + String)`. After the user selects an item in the list I want to extract two original values Integer and String. Can you suggest how to achive that? Im assuming that Integer value is automatically converted to String, therefore `getSelectedValue()` returns one String object.

Comment: split the string around -. The string in position 0 is the Integer, and the string in position 1 is the string

Comment: show us some of the code?